# Дарвин не прав

Tags: этимология, ономастика

Вы не находите что "расшифровка" слов такова:
Бондарев- фамилия возможно происходящая от профессии бондарь, или сын бондаря.

Вы же не хотите сказать, что например "топор" это изначально родовое имя, которое дало название фамилии Топоров.

Уважаемая вами госпожа Суперанская, в многочисленных статьях о происхождении имен, которые я имел удовольствие лицезреть, сводит объяснения именно от имени к фамилии (или религиозное происхождение), а не от профессии, предмета к фамилии. Где же здесь логика.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, ответ на этот вопрос должен быть дан не на уровне эмоций, а при помощи изучения источников. У Вас есть документальное подтверждение происхождения фамилий типа "Топоров"? Причем не единичного (всяко в жизни бывает), а массового?

Answer (score 1):

Фамилия Топоров произошла скорее всего от прозвища Топор: Топоров сын. Все фамилии на -ов образованы подобным образом из притяжательных прилагательных: сын чей? - Иванов, Николаев (от имён), Кузнецов, Певцов (от занятий людей), Дроздов, Баранов (от прозвищ). Суперанская, кстати, очень хорошо объясняет происхождение фамилий. Верьте ей.

Comment: Госпожа Суперанская именно делает акцент на происхождении от имени или религиозное. Фамилия Балясин например ведет к предмету. Она же почти всегда ведет к тому, что человека так звали (Условно: "Баляс" - потому что человек был несмелым , всего боялся), либо дает религиозное объяснение имени. Но это же глупо все сводить к двум видам трактовок.

Comment: Ну хорошо, пусть фамилия "Топоров" произошла от предмета "Топор", а не от имени. Но откуда же взялась сама структуру фамилии? Почему не "Топоран", или "Топорный", или "Топорша"? Да мало ли что можно придумать... Но нет, форма с "-ов" - самая продуктивная.  
Именно потому, что она выражает притяжательность: Чей? - Иванов. А как Вы "переведете" Топоров? Принадлежащий топору?  
Конечно, когда схема стала уже привычной, некоторые новые фамилия могли быть созданы искусственно. Но это все-таки исключения.

Answer (score 0):

Очень много фамилий произошло от профессий, например Плотников, Столяров и т.п. Более чем уверен, что Бондарев, как и Бондаренко, произошли именно от профессии бондаря, а не наоборот. Вначале был топор, а потом уже Топоров.

Comment: Да, сначала был топор как предмет, потом человек по прозвищу Топор, потом уже фамилия Топоров. Цепочка такова. Топоров - это сын Топора-человека.  а не топора-инструмента.

Comment: >Бондарев, как и Бондаренко, произошли именно от профессии бондаря, а не наоборот.

А кто уверяет что наоборот: сначала была фамилия, а потом появилась профессия? :DDD

Comment: Ну дык. Всегда ж приятно придумать себе химеру - а потом её же с блеском опровегнуть.

Answer (score 0):

Есть разные пути появления фамилий. Основной массив - от отчеств (соответственно, имен), но есть и другие. Например, Долгих, Черных и т.п.
Есть и случайные, окказиональные фамилии, результат словотворчества отдельного человека или просто ошибки. Вот, например, фамилия **Ультраиванов** (знаю такую семью). Явно не от отчества! И даже самая "нормальная" фамилия может быть созданной искусственно, например, для подкидыша. Но это не отменяет общих тенденций.

Answer (score 0):

Чего я не нахожу - так это смысла в вопросе.
Ещё меньше мне нравится постоянные отсылки в личности Суперанской, а не к её конкретным работам (среди которых, вполне допускаю, могут быть нуждающиеся в критике).